# How can I write this code in JRuby?

Tags: java, ruby, jruby

Java :

```
import java.util.*;
import org.scribe.builder.*;
import org.scribe.builder.api.*;
import org.scribe.model.*;
import org.scribe.oauth.
```

JRuby :

```
java_import org.scribe.builder.*;
java_import org.scribe.builder.api.*;
java_import org.scribe.model.*;
java_import org.scribe.oauth.*;
```

Getting this error JRuby :

```
wrong constant name OrgScribeBuilder*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `include_package`:https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/JRuby-Reference#importing-a-package-into-a-class-or-module

Answer (score 0):

you should have got the error `NameError: cannot load Java class org.scribe.builder.`. Java classes must be imported with their full qualified name.

```
require 'java'
require 'scribe-1.3.4.jar'
# you can't use the start import -> java_import 'org.scribe.builder.*'
java_import 'org.scribe.builder.ServiceBuilder'
service = ServiceBuilder.new;
```

or as @Idan wrote use the include_package

```
require 'java'
require 'scribe-1.3.4.jar'

# use include_package to have an analogue way like in Java -> 'import org.scribe.builder.*'
module Demo
  include_package 'org.scribe.builder'
  service = ServiceBuilder.new;
end
```

cheers Frank